# Automatically increment a variable in PHP at specific times

Tags: php, cron

Ok, so I'm fairly new to php. I couldn't find a solution to my problem on the web, so here it is. I'm developing on XAMPP for Windows, and on my webpage there is an array with IDs ranging from 1 to 1000. Then I have a variable called $currentid which represents the current ID.

```
$currentid=$ids[0]
```

The problem is I need some way for this currentid variable to automatically incremement by 1 at midnight (UTC) every single day, and then refresh the page. So for example, I'd want tomorrow that variable to be:

```
$currentid=$ids[1]
```

I heard something about Cron jobs, but I don't know how they work or if they are the only method of doing this. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Why would you not just calculate it if it's just incremented by 1 every day at midnight...?

Comment: There's this thing called "google". if you'd use it, you'd find things like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron to answer your questions.

Comment: Where is this variable.... is it from a database, or held in a cache, or a filesystem file?

Answer (score 0):

you can give the script a get var, for example:

```
yourscript.php?old_id=[value]
```

use javascript to reload the page at a specific time...

in the next step catch the value after reloading and increment it

```
$id = $_GET[old_id];
$id++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Marc B is correct, you need a cron job.